# Unable to translate "Show/hide questions" in questionnaire section of election

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, localization

The questionnaire section on the election pages, e.g. [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5#questionnaire) has links to 'Show' and 'Hide' questions:

> [image]

> [image]

There're no strings to translate in Traducir.

Also there's a little inconsistency with cases: questions/Questions

Comment: It seems that strings were not found due to case inconsistency, so the current question maybe transformed to fixing the word case inconsistency.

Comment: It looks like the strings do exist in Traducir ([Show Questions](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16315), [Hide questions](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16300)), and the translations there do seem to be applied on the linked SOru election page – which I'm guessing is what you mean by the above comment – but I'll still share this with the devs so that they can make the capitalization consistent between the two strings (i.e. so they're both in sentence case).

Answer (score 3):

We've updated this string to match existing casing. Also, your pointing this out helped us to find a semi-unrelated unrelated javascript bug with how we're scrolling you to the questionnaire when you click that button, so, thank you! And thanks for the original report.